# C - Excess elements in array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, warnings

I am learning C and I am playing around with pointers and arrays.  I am trying to create an array of pointers with the code below:

```
const int NUM_P = 50; // Line 10
char *pS[NUM_P] = { NULL }; // Line 11
```

I am getting the following warnings and errors when I compile:

→ gcc array.c -o array
array.c: In function ‘main’:
array.c:11: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
array.c:11: warning: excess elements in array initializer
array.c:11: warning: (near initialization for ‘pS’)

I cannot figure this error out, I have looked online and been unable to find a explanation and solution of the problem.

Can anyone help out?

Cheers

Eef

Comment: What are you trying to do in "char *pS[NUM_P] = { NULL }; " ?

Comment: Perhaps the syntax of C is a bit confusing. In C, const int means that you are creating a variable that you plan not to change after initialisation. In C++ it is a true constant and can be used as you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is the initialization line (`= {NULL};`) because apparently you can't initialize an array that way *when the array's size is a variable*.  If you use `#define NUM_P 50` to force the array size to be a true compile-time constant, then the array would not have a variable size, and your initialization method would compile fine.

As a side note, the difference between `#define NUM_P 50` and `const int NUM_P = 50` is that C89 does not allow the use of variables as array dimensions, but C99 does; however, C99 is not fully supported by all compilers yet.  The fact that gcc accepts your character array with a size of `NUM_P` is not C89-compliant.

Technically, you could use a flag on the command line to tell gcc that you want to compile in C99:

```
gcc -std=c99 FILE.c
```

By the way, when learning C, start at the top of the errors listed and work down from there.  In this case, the *warnings* are not of any concern until you've taken care of the *error* at the top: "variable-sized object may not be initialized".

Comment: Thanks, taking the '= {NULL};'  out fixed the issue and it runs ok.  I am actually following the book 'C - Novice to Professional' and it had that as part of source for a tutorial!  It now works, thanks again.  Eef